# Cannot Call determinedVisibility() never saw a connection for PID

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We recently updated our mobile app from Worklight 5.0.6 to MobileFirst 7.0.  Before the update, we didn't support 4.4 and above due to Cordova issues with the JSON Store. Now, we're supporting the newer versions of Android.

The application works great on all iOS devices and Android 4.x devices. On Android 5 and above, I'm experiencing a white screen on clicking our login button.

```
$("#loginButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#realmPopupMenu').popup("open");
});
```

In the Android Log, I am seeing this error:

```
06-18 07:34:57.329: W/AmazonAppstore.AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate(2325): Unable to determine asin for package com.MyGPCMobile.  Skipping metadata update.
06-18 07:34:58.709: W/AmazonAppstore.AppManagerAndroidPackageDelegate(2325): Unable to determine asin for package com.MyGPCMobile.  Skipping metadata update.
06-18 07:35:02.129: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:02.529: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:03.469: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:10.879: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:11.769: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:30.579: D/DMCFaceEngine(919): caSmartDP_DetermineFixedDevice : TmpFile exists /data/smart_stay_hash.dmc 
06-18 07:35:30.579: D/DMCFaceEngine(919): caSmartDP_DetermineFixedDevice : FIXED OR NOT  : difference 300.376667
06-18 07:35:30.579: D/DMCFaceEngine(919): caSmartDP_DetermineFixedDevice : TmpFile making start /data/smart_stay_hash.dmc 
06-18 07:35:30.589: D/DMCFaceEngine(919): caSmartDP_DetermineFixedDevice : TmpFile making end /data/smart_stay_hash.dmc 
06-18 07:35:30.589: D/DMCFaceEngine(919): caSmartDP_SmartStay : [5.000000] determine[300] result [-1]
06-18 07:35:35.919: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:35.929: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:38.739: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:39.689: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
06-18 07:35:39.699: W/BindingManager(2501): Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 2501
```

What is causing this error on Android 5 versions and above?

Comment: That code snippet and single log line is not helping. If you are able to reproduce this outside of your app - please provide that (=project). Also, provide the full LogCat.

Comment: Idan, sent you a Dropbox link of the project

Comment: Can you provide the Full LogCat?

Comment: Idan, what I pasted above was the full content of the LogCat tab in Eclipse from the time I ran the app on the phone until the time I got the white screen. Is there something else you're looking for that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Not sure. It suspiciously lacks content...

Comment: Tested the app in Nexus 5 and Samsung Galaxy S6, both running Android 5.x; did not experience the reported behavior...

Comment: I've got the same problem, have you managed to fix it yet?

Comment: Strider, No I haven't yet. I am updating JQuery now to see if that resolves the issue. I've narrowed it down further to a mobile.changepage function which I updated to mobile.navigate.  But I still get the white screen.

Comment: Updated to Jquery 1.4.5 and this fixed this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated to Jquery Mobile 1.4.5 and this fixed the white screen issue. The issue was with Jquery pop dialog and also mobile.changepage & mobile.navigate. Updating the version of Jquery Mobile to 1.4.5 fixed this.

Comment: So the guess was a correct one. Cool. Glad it got solved. :)